# Mime Types with Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, unity-game-engine, mime-types

I am trying to upload a game I made on unity. Whenever I run the html file it all works, but whenever I publish it says that the file failed to download. I realize this is because it doesn't recognize the file type .unity3d and that I need to add a mime type, but how? I am using google app engine and I assume it is in the app.yaml where I need to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the `.unity3d` file in [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs), and set the mime type on the object to `application/vnd.unity`. Serve it via a URL to your user's browser by embedding the link in the HTML page that your app serves. If they have the unity3d player installed, the browser will know what to do at this point.

Comment: Do I put the .unity3d file in the storage browser? Also, where do I set the mime type for the object?

Comment: Check out the docs linked in the user's answer to figure out how to set the mime type on a bucket object, or put objects, or what an "object" or a "bucket" is in the context of GCS is, for that matter.

Comment: GCS is not a storage browser but a storage system, which you interact with programmatically. You can use the [cloud storage client library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/), or use [`gsutil`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) - a [cloud sdk](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/) tool makes this functionality available through a shell command. Put the binary object in GCS, and do [a](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/functions#open) little reading to figure out how to set the MIME type. </dtrush>

Comment: There *is* a GCS storage browser in the [dev console](https://console.developers.google.com/), however, just to be clear.